# Create new guard clause

Tags: function, pattern-matching, elixir

In Elixir, how would I go about creating a new guard clause for a function? Obviously, I've seen that you can't just call any function in a `when` statement, but it would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
defmodule Player do
  def play_card(player), do: []
  def play_card(player) when has_cards(player), do: ...
  # Define has_cards as guard clause?
end
```

Comment: pattern match the cards in the arg to play_card: def play_card(player=Player[cards: cards]) when is_list(cards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Kernel.defguard/1` (or `defguardp/1`) to do this now:

```
defmodule Player do
  defstruct [:name, cards: []]
  defguard has_cards(cards) when cards != []

  def play_card(%__MODULE__{cards: cards}) when has_cards(cards), do: []
  def play_card(_player), do: []
end
```

Documentation: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defguard/1

However, guards of necessity are still very simple constructs, so you can't really put complex logic in them. For reference, here's what you can put in guards: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/guards.html#list-of-allowed-expressions

Answer (score 25):

The short answer is: you can't.

The long answer is that you can define macros and they will work in guards as long as they are made of valid guards expressions. But that is non-trivial for complex guards so it is better avoided unless you really have to.

The list of valid guards can be found in the getting started guide: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/case-cond-and-if.html#expressions-in-guard-clauses

A sample implementation of a "complex" guard macro can be found in Elixir source: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/5d34fcdccd20bf38c4f2a13f8adeb78e22b4e74c/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L1574

Comment: There is another great example [in the SweetElixir workshop](https://github.com/cromwellryan/sweetelixir/blob/master/advanced/pattern_matching.md#record-pattern-matching) repo. `is_male` and `is_female` macros are used as guards.

Comment: Another good reference on this is at http://keathley.io/2016/04/09/elixir-guard-clauses.html , but be sure to check out Elixir's naming conventions with regards to this: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/master/elixir/naming-conventions.html#trailing-question-mark-foo . The complex guard macro name should in the form of `is_[x]` and not `[x]?`.